# Success message when saving data successfully in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

```
            axios
            .post(
              "/api/product/store",{
                   id: this.id
               })
            .then((res) => {
              var variant = "danger";
              var icon = "XIcon";
              var message = "Thất bại";
              if (res.data.error == 0) {
                var variant = "success";
                var icon = "ArrowDownCircleIcon";
                var message = res.data.message;
                window.location.reload();
              }
              this.$toast({
                component: ToastificationContent,
                props: {
                  title: message,
                  icon: icon,
                  variant: variant,
                },
              });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
            });
```

My problem is: When the message is displayed, it only loads the page, so when the page reloads, it loses the message. Is there a way for it to reload the previous page and then display the following message? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of reloading your page? If you want to show the updated data on UI, vue by itself will do it for you. so you don't need to do that.

Or if the page reloading is a must for you, you can take your toast to your root page and call it from your current child page. In this case, whether you reload a page or not the message will be displayed.

Comment: I am doing vue with laravel. I am adding data to the database. The laravel controller side returns success, I want the extra page to reload the page and display the new message.

Comment: Well then refetch the data, and update the data value. Vue will re-render your page whenever you change the model.